# How to show gradle stacktrace on heroku deployment?

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, jhipster

I'm attempting to deploy a gradle java app to heroku (based on jhipster).  I can build and run it locally with "heroku local", but when I attempt to deploy it remotely I get an error when it attempts to build the application (while executing ./gradlew stage).  The error is:

```
...
remote:        Download https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.0.0.CR1/mapstruct-processor-1.0.0.CR1.pom
remote:        Download https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.0.0.CR1/mapstruct-processor-1.0.0.CR1.jar
remote:        :bower FAILED

remote:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
remote:        
remote:        * What went wrong:
remote:        Execution failed for task ':bower'.
remote:        > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'bower''
remote:        
remote:        * Try:
remote:        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
remote:        
remote:        BUILD FAILED
```

I imagine if I could see the stacktrace it may clarify the problem, but I don't know how to pass in a command line argument (--stacktrace) to a gradle build on the heroku remote server.  I would try it manually with a (heroku run bash) but I can't since this is the first deploy and there is no code on the dyno yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that the `bower` command is not available. In order to add it to the build, you will need to add the Node.js buildpack to your app by running these commands:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/gradle
```

This will run the Node.js buildpack first (after you `git push`), which will install node and any dependencies in your `package.json`. Then it will run the Gradle buildpack.

There are a few other things you might have to configure, and I have a [blog post on doing this with Maven](http://jkutner.github.io/2015/05/25/jhipster-heroku-git.html). But in general the same principles apply for Gradle.

Comment: I should note, you'll probably also need to run `npm install bower grunt-cli --save` and commit your `package.json` to Git.

Comment: I had the same issue but with the `npm` command. Tried to do this in the Heroku web UI but it only works if you add the nodejs buildpack before the gradle one as @codefinger says

Answer (score 2):

You can also deploy to Heroku using the [heroku deploy plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-deploy).

```
./gradlew clean -Pprod bootRepackage -x test
heroku deploy:jar --jar build/libs/*.war
```